# How to show image from RSS feed using ionic framework

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I just learning about ionic. can u help me for this problem,
Somehow i can't show the picture in android

I use this js code for taking data from Rss feed

```
.controller("feedCtrl", function($http, $scope){$scope.init = function(){
$http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "num":"100", "q": "http://www.bola.net/feed/" } })
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.rssTitle = data.responseData.feed.title;
    $scope.rssUrl = data.responseData.feed.feedUrl;
    $scope.rssSiteUrl = data.responseData.feed.link;
    $scope.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;
//  $scope.author = data.responseData.feed.author;
//  $scope.descriptionin = data.responseData.feed.description;
    //$scope.publishedDate = data.responseData.feed.publishedDate;
    //$scope.content = data.responseData.feed.content;
    //$scope.categories = data.responseData.feed.categories;
})
.error(function(data) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + data);
});}  $scope.browse = function(v){
window.open(v, "_system", "location=yes")}});
```

And in my view i use this code,

```
 <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="feedCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="list">
      <a class="item" ng-href="{{entry.link}}" ng-click="window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'location=no'); return false;" ng-repeat="entry in entries">
        <b>{{entry.title}}</b><br/>
        <b>{{entry.link}}</b><br/>
        <b>{{entry.author}}</b><br/>
        <b>{{entry.publishedDate}}</b><br/>
        <b>{{entry.contentSnippet}}</b><br/>
        <b>{{entry.content}}</b><br/>
        <span ng-bind-html="entry.contentSnippet"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

The Result of Entry content in Android page is like this,

```
<img src="http://cdn.klimg.com/****.net/library/upload/20/2016/07/175/jose-mourinho_30eb505.jpg" align="left" hspace="5" width="100"/>Pelatih Manchester United Jose Mourinho mengungkapkan pasukannya sudah siap untuk menjalani laga menghadapi Galatasaray yang akan berlangsung di Gothenburg, Swedia, pada hari Sabtu (30/7).]]>
```

But what i want is just the link of the image,

```
http://cdn.klimg.com/****.net/library/upload/20/2016/07/175/jose-mourinho_30eb505.jpg
```

How can i do that?,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new function that extracts the src like this:

```
$scope.getPhoto = function(entry) {
    return entry.content.match(/src="([^"]*)/)[1];
}
```

And then Change : `<b>{{entry.content}}</b><br/>`

to :  `<b>{{getPhoto(entry)}}</b><br/>`

Comment: hey @Akis, i've try but same result.

Comment: @windysinaga i have updated my answer, this will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

All Rss feeds would not provide images , But some news channels like CNN will provide images in the index mediaGroups ...

```
{{entry.mediaGroups[0].url }}
```

there are totally 11 images with different resolutions ...